# Is Strong law of Large numbers equal to pointwise convergence?

Tags: law-of-large-numbers

**1. function pointwise convergence**

$\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $E$ if the following equation holds,
$$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)  , $$
for every $x\in E$.

**2. Strong Law of Large Numbers**

A sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ converges almost surely to a random variable $X$ if for **almost** every $\omega \in \Omega$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{X_n(\omega)}=X(\omega).$$

**3. The relation of above**

I found out that these two are amazingly similar. When the **almost** is removed, they become exactly the same.

The first definition is from *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* Definition 7.1. The second definition is from [What is the difference between the weak and strong law of large numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024255/what-is-the-difference-between-the-weak-and-strong-law-of-large-numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not equal.

We say that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere if $\mu\{\omega: f_n(\omega) \not\to f(\omega)\} = 0$.

It is obvious that pointwise convergence implies convergence almost surely, since if $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then $\mu \{\omega: f_n(\omega) \not\to f(\omega)\} = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

For a counterexample of the other direction, we work with the lebesgue measure $\mu = \lambda$. Consider your favorite pointwise convergence limit $f_n \to f$ on the reals and change the value of $f$ in your favorite point and denote this adaption of $f$ with $g$. Then $f_n \to g$ almost surely (since singeltons have Lebesgue measure zero) but not pointwise because we destroyed the convergence in the point where we changed $f$.

Comment: So $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere means there can be a measure zero exceptional set, but $f_n \to f$ pointwise means there is no single exceptional point.

Comment: Yes, the convergence is everywhere except on a set of measure zero.