# convergence a.s. and in probability of discrete random variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems, almost-everywhere

Assume $X_{n}$ is a sequence of random variables taking values from some finite discrete space. Next, assume 
$$
P(X_{n} = c) \to 1,
$$
for some $c$, as $n \to \infty$.

I would like to find an example of a sequence $X_{n}$, such that
$$
X_{n} \overset{a.s.}{\not\to} c
$$
i.e. the convergence a.s. does not hold.

Comment: Take a look at [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3673386/631717).