# Mean and kinda almost sure convergence relation

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Considering:

Almost sure convergence as $X_n \xrightarrow[]{\text{a.s}} X \Leftrightarrow P(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n=X)=1$ and

Mean $L_p$-convergence as $X_n \xrightarrow[]{\text{mean}}  X \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}|X_n-X|^p \rightarrow 0$

Are there any examples of such Random variables that they converge in terms of mean and **do not** converge in terms of 'almost sure' convergence and vice-versa - converging a.s (in terms of definition listed above) and **do not** converging in terms of mean.

May you help me with this one? (Doing this as a part of my types of RV convergence implication tree proof building - I've used infamous Riss model and similar during proofing, however don't have any ideas for this two - I want to prove that mean (so-called $L_p$) convergence do not necessarily imply a.s convergence and vice versa).

Comment: Surely your definition of almost sure convergence should have the probability equalling $1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959062/probability-density-functions-that-demonstrate-the-difference-between-the-weak-a/3959071#3959071

Comment: @jlammy oddly yes..

Comment: What do you mean by "oddly yes"? The thing that you wrote, with $0$ on the RHS, is literally the complete opposite of convergence. I'm sure it's just a typo in your text -- it should be $1$ on the RHS.

Comment: @jlammy maybe it is not exactly a.s convergence, I'm living not in the USA/England/etc and we call it here a.s convergence)

Comment: Like I said, I think that it's just a typo -- the RHS must be $1$. Think about it this way -- say that $X_n=1$ identically. Then under your definition, the $X_n$ don't converge to the rv $X=1$! In other words, even the constant sequence doesn't converge under your definition! If there are mathematically literate aliens out there, I'm sure that they'd like their constant sequences to converge too.

Comment: @jlammy, oh, sorry, sleepy now, of course it is 1 there. However during my attempts I was assuming 1 ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$X_n=\begin{cases}n^3 & \text{with probability }n^{-2} \\ 0 & \text{with probability }1-n^{-2}.\end{cases}$$
Then $X_n\to0$ almost surely: indeed, $\sum\mathbb P(\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon)\leq\sum n^{-2}$ which converges, so we can apply Borel-Cantelli. But $\mathbb E[X_n]=n\to\infty$.

---

Now consider independent rvs
$$Y_n=\begin{cases}1 & \text{with probability }n^{-1} \\ 0 & \text{with probability }1-n^{-1}.\end{cases}$$
Then $\mathbb E[Y_n]=1/n\to0$, but $Y_n$ doesn't converge a.s. Indeed, as $\sum\mathbb P(Y_n=1)=+\infty$ and the events $\{Y_n=1\}$ are independent, the second Borel-Cantelli lemma gives that $$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{Y_n=1\}\right)=1,$$
so we can't have $Y_n\to0$ almost surely.

Comment: And are both cases (a.s -> mean; mean -> a.s) described here?

Comment: @9cloudalpha First example converges a.s. to $0$, but doesn't converge in mean; second example converges in mean to $0$, but doesn't converge a.s.

Comment: And $\Omega$ for $X$ is $[0; +\infty]$?